Delete Tables Matillion Component
I want to delete multiple tables, and the table names are in the grid variable. for example [['table_1'], ['table_2']]. But when I define the grid variable, it says input required.



Do you have default values assigned in your Grid Variable?

use the grid iterator component and feed that into the delete table component.
